# Can you use grid-auto-flow: dense without knowing how many grid items you'll have

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm attempting to style a list of features, and would like to lay them out in a dense grid, but haven't been able to do so.

Currently, the features are set out using a flex box. As a broad example:

```css
.list {
  width: 400px;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-item.short {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

.list-item.medium {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
}

.list-item.long {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item medium">MEDIUM</li>
  <li class="list-item medium">MEDIUM</li>
  <li class="list-item long">LONG</li>
  <li class="list-item short">SHORT</li>
  <li class="list-item long">LONG</li>
  <li class="list-item short">SHORT</li>
  <li class="list-item long">LONG</li>
</ul>
```

If you run the snippet, you'll see gaps in the pseudo code next to the `medium` length items that I'd like filled by the `short` length items.

So, getting from:

[image: Before]

To:

[image]

It seemed to me `grid-auto-flow: row dense` would be perfect for this, though I can't get it working. Is there a way I can do this?

Things worth noting: in real life I don't know the length, order nor number of the features coming through.

I'd hoped this would be a simple as:

```
.list {
  width: 400px;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}
```

But that doesn't help - is there a way to layout the columns / rows to achieve this? I wonder if `dense` only works to plug in items around others with a fixed `grid-area`?

Comment: this is a lot of job for CSS only

Comment: You have to *define* a grid for `dense` to fit into and you haven't done that.

Comment: Thanks both. @Paulie_D I think that answers my question then. I presume given the amount of unknowns in my scenario it's impossible to define such a grid? All attempts with `repeat(auto-fill/fit...` have fallen short for me. If that's the case, let me know and feel free to drop in as an answer :)